# Pad a Python string to a specified length

Tags: python, python-3.x, task

A string is given in which there are no beginning and ending spaces. It is necessary to change it so that the length of the string becomes equal to the specified length, greater than the current length of the string. This should be done by inserting additional spaces between the words. The number of spaces between individual words should not differ by more than one space (that is, spaces are added evenly).

The string itself is entered by the user from the keyboard. The teacher said that I need to solve the problem using slices, but I don't understand exactly how. The problem is that it is not known in advance how long the entered string will be. And how many initial gaps there will be in it. At the same time, it is necessary that the length of the final line exactly matches the length that the user entered.

Here's what I've come up with so far. This code evenly adds spaces to the beginning and end of the entered line, if there were no spaces in it initially.

```
line_0 = input('Enter the required line:\n')
print('Current string length:\n', len(line_0), sep = '')
num_0 = len(line_0)
num_1 = int(input('Enter the total length of the string:\n'))
num_d = num_1 - num_0
s = line_0.count(' ')
line_1 = ''
if s == 0:
    if (num_d % 2) != 0:
        cup_1 = ' ' * (num_d // 2 + 1)
        cup_2 = ' ' * (num_d // 2)
        line_1 = cup_1 + line_0 + cup_2
    else:
        cup_1 = ' ' * (num_d // 2)
        line_1 = cup_1 + line_0 + cup_1
print("'^' - the beginning and end of the line (not included in the 
length of the final line).")
print('The resulting string is long ', len(line_1), ':\n', '^', line_1, 
'^', sep = '')
```

Comment: See `ljust`, `rjust`, `center`, `zfill` and other functions for strings which pad or manipulate strings. [More](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html).

Answer (score 0):

First you need to figure how many spaces you will have to add.
In the same time, you'll split the initial string in a list of words.
Than, you calculate the minimum amount of spaces to add to each word, and the remaining that you'll add to the n first words.
Finally you add the spaces and maxe the words and spaces a str.

```
initial_sentence = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
spaces_to_add = int(input("Length needed : ")) - len(initial_sentence)
words = initial_sentence.split(" ")
number_words = len(words) - 1

min_spaces_added = spaces_to_add // number_words
spaces_remaining = spaces_to_add % number_words

final_string = ""

for word_ID in range(number_words) :
   final_string = final_string + words[word_ID] + " "*(1+min_spaces_added) #the initial space after the word that has been removed by the .split() + the minimum required
   if word_ID+1 <= spaces_remaining :
      final_string += " "
final_string += words[-1]#the last word
print(final_string)
```